# Trying to start a thread based on a users choice

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a Combobox with many choices. What the user chooses takes them to a case statement. In this case one of the items that gets choosen is a string. Now this string I want to use to take start a specific function thread. e.g. I have function

```
    public void DoWorkAP(){}
```

and another

```
    public void DoWorkAG(){}
```

From the Combo box the user makes a choice and the case statemtn will have a string called sWhichWork and that is set to either "DoWorkAG" or "DoWorkAP"

Now in the UI code I have a thread

```
    Thread t = null;
```

And when a button is pressed a function is called and in this function I have

```
    t = new Thread(sWhichWork);


    t.Start();
```

This seemed good as I woudl exect sWhichWork to be substituted with "DoWorkAG" or "DoWorkAP" but instead I get

"cannot convert from 'string' to System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart' "

Now I take out the SWhichWorks and have the following

```
    t = new Thread(DoWorkAG); 


    t.Start();
```

This is good as it compiles and takes me to the correct place. So the question is how can I have a variable string choosen from the combox to the case stament take me to the same place?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two options, I'd go for

```
t = new Thread(sWhichWork == "DoWorkAG" ? DoWorkAG : DoWorkAP);
```

This would work as well:

```
t = new Thread(this.getType().GetMethod(sWhichWork).Invoke(this, new object[]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just switch on the thread:

```
var action = myComboBox.Text;
new Thread(() => {
 if (action == "1") F1();
 else F2();
});
```

Super simple.